# IIS 6 Redirects When Incoming Url Has Extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, iis-6

I have to write redirects in my MVC global.asax file to accommodate an IIS 6 server. However, when I get to the old urls with extensions (.html), the server is not redirecting. Here is an example of my redirect code:

```
if (url.Contains("contact.html"))
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
            Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.mysite.com/contact");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: Did you change/remove the handler for .html in IIS to allow ASP.NET to intercept the request?

Comment: I see what you're doing but it seems like you're using a screwdriver instead of a power drill. Why not create a route redirecting to an action method called `contact` in `home` controller?

Comment: This is an outdated url from an old version of the site. I already have a route for the regular contact page. I'm trying to redirect when the url contains .html. Am I making sense?

Comment: Steven, I don't have access to the server. If that is the issue, then I will have to have the server admin handle.

Comment: I think, in case rewritting is not installed then it can be easily done with HTTPHandlers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was due to the need to add the related http handlers to IIS 6. Thanks, Steven!